# Cant find Laravel valet's nginx and php configration file directory

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, laravel-valet, valet

I am using Laravel valet and working on getting data from API which takes more than 3 minutes to return result. Now the problem is when I use curl or `get_file_contents`, I get timeout error ""504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.23.1" in 60 seconds and no matter which `ini` settings I add with code it doesn't change. So I searched how I can change nginx and PHP config settings in Laravel valet and the solution was to find the files in following `directory:usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`

The problem is that in my latest mac OS there is no folder called *etc* in `usr/local diretory`. Can anyone please help me. I really want to bypass this and make it work but I cant find any solution.

I tried adding following code in PHP script to avoid changing configuration files but it didn't work and I still get timeout at 60 seconds.

```php
ini_set('max_execution_time', 2400);
set_time_limit(900);
```

Also I tried using curl request with following settings:

```php
$ch=curl_init();
        $timeout=2400;
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $timeout);
       curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
       $result=curl_exec($ch);
       curl_close($ch);
```

I just checked my valet logs and it shows following

> 2022/12/22 23:52:12 [error] 876#0: *2343 upstream timed out (60:
> Operation timed out) while reading response header from upstream,
> client: 127.0.0.1, server: , request: "POST /admin/ajax HTTP/1.1",
> upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/Users/username/.config/valet/valet.sock", host:
> "localsite.test", referrer:
> "http://localsite.test/admin/add-user"

Comment: Try clearing cache ```php artisan config:cache```. And try adding this ```ini_set('MAX_EXECUTION_TIME', -1); ```

Comment: @matheenulla thankyou for suggestion. I tried it but this didn't work even though i put it right in my PHP controller in the top. I am guessing it has something to do with Nginx settting since i get following error "504 Gateway Time-out nginx/1.23.1". The problem is I can't find the configration file located in macos.

Answer (score 0):

try

> ~/.config/valet

Maybe it has Nginx config files folder.